# Which processes are used by console application run from a web application

Tags: .net, performance, web-applications, process, console-application

In a web application I need to execute file conversion (as example from jpeg to pdf) when a local file is uploaded to the server. 
I decided to delegate this task to a console application in order to detach it from the general web application. The console application code is run each time a user upload a local document and returns the name of the converted file in case of success ( test.jpg as input will return as test.pdf).

Since I need to know whether the file was properly converted before proceeding, **am I loosing the benefits of delegating the task to an external process** (since the code of the console app would run on a separate process, right)?

Since the uploaded file are converted only to pdf or .doc, I can change the string representing the filename accordingly and then eventually check if that file exists when needed in the following steps, but I want to break to all operation if the conversion fails, rather than produce any mid result taht should be discarded.

Here the code I designed to call the console application:

```
HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
string extension = fileInfo.Extension;
ConvertCommand conv = new ConvertCommand();
string convertedFile = conv.Run(file.InputStream, extension, targetFilePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good idea not to execute long-running tasks in the context of a web request; file conversion is probably such a "long-running" task. Running the conversion synchronously is the issue, not necessarily whether you run the code in code behind, a shell app, or a web service.

Worker threads are scarce resources on web servers (comparatively, that is); most web servers expect a web request to be dealt with within a second or so. If requests take longer, the server needs to manage more worker threads; this in turn may slow down the processing for each individual thread, which means they take longer, and the whole thing can go non-linear very quickly.

The proper solution is to use [asynchronous processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx). As long as you process the conversion asynchronously, I think it doesn't really matter what the specific implementation is - you're far less likely to run into scalability issues. For extra bonus joy, you can use distributed processing if you have to by delegating the task to a separate service.

Comment: +1 for the good hints. Originally my idea was to use an asynchronous solution and let the console app run. However I need to know whether the conversion failed or not in order to proceed with the workflow. I wil try the workaround to rename the original fle into the target extension (pdf) and then check if the file exist before using it. However the problem is that I can request the file before it will be properly generated from the console app, resulting as it would have failed since not available...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of console application I would recommend to use a Windows service for image conversion. Communication with it can be done via WCF.